# Get value from nested dictionary that consist of list using dot string path

Tags: python

I have this function:

```
def deep_get(dictionary, keys, default=None):
    return reduce(
        lambda d, key: d.get(key, default) if isinstance(d, dict) else default,
        keys.split("."),
        dictionary,
    )
```

Now it works like that:

```
person1 = {'person': {'name': {'first': 'John'}}}
print(deep_get(person1, "person.name.first"))   # John

person2 = {'person': {'names': ['Adam', 'John']}}
print(deep_get(person2, "person.names"))        # ['Adam', 'John']
print(deep_get(person2, "person.names[0]"))     # None
```

How can I change it to support also lists nested in dictionary?

i.e. in this example `deep_get(person2, "person.names[0]")` should return `'Adam'` instead of `None`.

Comment: Couldn't you use `deep_get(person2, "person.names")[0]` ?

Comment: This is an example dictionary and the one that I am using is more complicated. I was looking for one line method that uses lambda function and dot string path notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expanded `deep_get` a bit.

```py
def deep_get(dictionary, keys, default=None):
    keys = keys.split('.')
    my_dict = dictionary[keys[0]]
    
    if len(keys) > 1:
        
        for key in keys[1:]:
            # In case key also has brackets
            if '[' in key:
                key, i = key.split('[')
                i = int(i.split(']')[0])
                my_dict = my_dict[key][i]
            
            else:
                my_dict = my_dict[key]

    return my_dict


person = {'person': {'name': {'first': 'John'}}}
print(deep_get(person, "person.name.first"))   # Jhon
person = {'person': {'names': ['Adam', 'John']}}
print(deep_get(person, "person.names"))       # ['Adam', 'Jhon']
print(deep_get(person, "person.names[0]"))   # Adam
```

The code basically navigates through all keys splitted by `.` with the special case of when brackets are present. This could definitely be optimized but it is a start.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can confirm that it is working. I am wonder if this could be done as one line method that uses lambda function :)